# Add point on the curve with only y point known

Tags: r

Is there any way to add the point on the curve with no *x* coordinate input?

 

e.g. I have the following data frame:

```
X    Y
11   15
12   15
13   16
17   20
19   20
```

and I use the `plot()` function to draw the curve.


I would like to specify the point `(13, 16)`, and I only know  the *y* value `16`
(Sounds ridiculous, but my actual data frame is too large to identify corresponding *x* value with specific *y* value)
Is there any way to approach this situation? `points()` function seems need both *x* and *y* value assigned.


Thanks!

Comment: Would you be satisfied plotting all points where y=16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've called your data `mydf`:

```
plot(mydf)
```

[image]

```
points(mydf[mydf$Y==16,], col="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

to highlight or prominent some points use points command
like
        points(data[data$Y==16,],pch=15,col="red")